# LINQ query many to many relation with additional field in join table

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I want to get all the records from Complaints either are assigned to users or not and list of all users that the complaint is assigned to grouped by each complaint with LINQ query Left join. these tables have many to many relation table with additional fields like Date etc. I tried a lot pleas if some one help me for this query.
thanks in advance

```cs
public class Complaint
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Complaint{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<AsignComplaintToUsers> asignComplaintToUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AsignComplaintToUsers> asignComplaintToUsers { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class AsignComplaintToUsers
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ComplaintId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ComplaintId")]
    public Complaint complaint { get; set; }


    public string? AsignToId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AsignTo")]
    public ApplicationUser applicationUser { get; set; }

    public string? AsignById { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Does this code work? In `AsignComplaintToUsers` class shouldn't it be ` [ForeignKey("AsignToId")]`

Comment: i don't know how to store two user on who assign the complaint to another user and second the user to whom the complaint was assign

Comment: If we do not have that column in AsignComplaintTousers table how could we make a many to many relation between ApplicationUser and Complaint table

Comment: That it another question. You can have another field such as `public ApplicationUser AssignedByUser{ get; set; }` and put attribute `[ForeignKey("AsignById ")]` on it.

Comment: thanks bro I got all records with following query

Answer (score 0):

with this query I solved the problem

```
var xyz = (from c in _context.complaints
                       join AC in _context.asignComplaintToUsers
                       on c.Id equals AC.ComplaintId into temp
                       from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

                       join AppUser in _context.applicationUsers
                       on t.AsignTo equals AppUser.Id into temp2
                       from t2 in temp2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                       select new
                       {
                           complaint = c,
                           asugnSugessionTousers = t,
                           usersWhoAsignedComplaints = t2

                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).